# Flipping/mirroring images

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

Rotating WPF images is pretty easy

```
imgCurrent.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(_rotationAngle);
```

What about horizontal and vertical mirroring ?

offtop:

```
In GDI(Drawing namespace) there was bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
```

is there tomething easy in wpf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005219/how-to-flip-image-in-wpf

Comment: From XAML you can use something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFImageEffects.aspx

From code-behind:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282107/how-do-i-make-a-reflection-effect-in-wpf-from-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = -1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a **ScaleTransform** with a **negative** X or Y scale factor